# How to include stdout/stderr redirection with command subsitution when command passed as a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection, command-substitution

I have the following script to detect when my network comes back on after restarting my router:

```
#!/bin/bash
pingCommand="ping 192.168.1.1 -c 3 &>/dev/null"

while [[ ! $($pingCommand) ]]; do
   sleep 3s;
done
```

However, when run in the terminal, it prints:

> ping: unknown host &>/dev/null

I ran the script with the `-x` option (to enable debugging) and found that

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -c 3 &>/dev/null
```

was being executed in the subshell as

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -c 3 '&>/dev/null'
```

How do I change my command substitution call so that bash does not put single quotes around the output redirection?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Don't store commands in variables. Use functions.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) They handle redirections and pipes without the quoting issues that plague variables.

It also doesn't make sense to try to capture ping's output when you're redirecting all of that output to `/dev/null`. If you just want to know if it worked or not, check its exit code.

```
pingCommand() {
    ping 192.168.1.1 -c 3 &>/dev/null
}

while ! pingCommand; do
   sleep 3s;
done
```

Comment: I am checking it's exit code, but the problem is that if there are any errors, they will display on the terminal, which I don't want.

Comment: They won't, because you have `&>/dev/null` which hides both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Originally, I didn't have the `&>/dev/null`, so it was showing the errors. When I added the `&>/dev/null` to my script above, that was when it broke, hence the question haha

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
pingCommand="ping 192.168.1.1 -c 3 &>/dev/null"

# set -x # uncomment to see what's going on

while ! eval $pingCommand ; do
   sleep 3s;
done
```

And you do not need the `[[ ]]` (expression evaluation) or the `$()` (output capture).

Of course, as John Kugelman suggested in another answer, using the functions avoids all the potential pitfalls associated with the `eval`.

Comment: or even   sh -c $pingCommand

Comment: @fche, `bash -c ...` you mean. POSIX shells can't `&>` redirection.